# Using Android NDK Details

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have [android - n.d.k] folder and i want to run a C program using .JAVA file , i am using eclipse & A.D.T. 22.3, i would like to know how to compile and run .java file not using command prompt but eclipse, and what steps and processing done in b\w as :

.java code --> .h [header file ] by /> (j a v a h) command in >c.m.d ..and so on.
if there's any tutorial kindly mention the link.

i have tried c.m.d. method but unable to get the (.dll) file from .c file,

Regards

Comment: You would not get a .dll file as Android is not based on windows.  Instead you will get one or more .so files, which are the traditional name of dynamic libraries on Linux - even the atypical-userspace unique-C-library Linux called "Android".

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html

See the above link that can help you.